# Java jpa connect to mysql with ssl

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, ssl

I have a mysql server with server private key self-certificate, and I want to connect it with my jsp application with spring and jpa (also with client private key self-certificate), but it does not work.

This is my code:

```
private EntityManager createEntityManager(){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String url = "", user = "", password = "";
    try {
        prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties"));
        url = prop.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        user = prop.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        password = prop.getProperty("jdbc.password");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Map <String, String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>();
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", user);
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", "true");    
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path_to_keystore_file");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path_to_truststore_file");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");      

    EntityManagerFactory fact = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("springappPU", properties);
    return fact.createEntityManager();  
}
```

The url property contains `useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true`.

Comment: What is the stacktrace? What is th exception message?

Comment: Provide the stacktrace..

Comment: wrong user or password, but it does not has sense because the same user and password, in mysql workbench, it works.